# cant open prohect in gethup

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: C:\Users\alhouda\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Install missing platform(s) and sync project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvYjO.png)

then i h\di all update 
put error massege her

Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsxsW.png)

Comment: where's the problem its exactly telling you what to do

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explaining. On the log click on the link that says install missing platforms and sync project. 
Click on that it will open a dialog from there you can install the missing platforms. 
After getting the missing platforms your project will be synced successfully. 
Make sure you are connected with internet and you are not using offline gradle build while doing this.

Comment: Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing platforms and sync project. Then rebuild your project to sync your project successfully. Then the error will be gone. Thanks!

Comment: Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

Comment: i tried changing classpath from 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' its worked for me

Comment: Also try to add the google() repository to build.gradle file.

Comment: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html